# how to skip request in `useLazyLoadQuery`

Tags: react-hooks, relayjs

How I can skip request/query in `useLazyLoadQuery`.

```js
import { useLazyLoadQuery } from 'react-relay/hooks';

const id = props.selectedId // id can be a number or null
const user = useLazyLoadQuery(query, {id}) // skip query/request network if id is null
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`@skip` or `@include` directive](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#directives). If the query ends up being empty following the directive conditions, no network request will be made. Consider the example:

```js
import { useLazyLoadQuery } from 'react-relay/hooks';

function MaybeUser(props) {
  const { userId } = props;
  //         is optional/nullable

  useLazyLoadQuery(
    graphql`
      query MaybeUserQuery($userId: ID!, $skip: Boolean!) {
        user(id: $userId) @skip(if: $skip) {
          fullName
        }
      }
    `,
    {
      userId: userId || '', // we need to pass something because of the query $userId type decleration
      skip: !userId,        // skip when there is no user ID
    },
  );

  return <magic />;
}
```

Empty `userId` produces an empty `MaybeUserQuery` resulting in **no network requests**.